# Returning a list from Java and displaying on HTML in play framework

Tags: java, javascript, html, playframework

Hi I am trying to list the words in a HTML div.The list of word is coming from Application.java in controller in play framework.Following is part of Application.java which returns the list.I am not sure if its correct.

```
Public stattic void explore(){
List<String> suggestionlist = new ArrayList<String>();
 try {  
      String s = null;
      int i=0;

        String[]callAndArgs= {"C:\\Python27\\python.exe","D:\\Dualist\\gui\\app\\controllers\\word2Vec_impl.py" , "D:\\Dualist\\data\\Short_tweets_ground_truth.csv"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(callAndArgs);
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        String[] words = stdInput.readLine().split("#");
        suggestionlist.addAll(Arrays.asList(words));
        for(int j = 0 ;j<=suggestionlist.size()-1 ;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(suggestionlist.get(j));
        }
        }  
     catch (IOException e) 
     {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
     } 

    // done! render!
    render(suggestionlist);
     }
```

In HTML I want to use these list data as select options .something like below

```
<select id="birthyear" name="birthyear">
    <option >suggestionlist[0]</option>
    <option >suggestionlist[1]</option>
    <option >suggestionlist[3]</option>
    <option >suggestionlist[4]</option>

</select>
```

I know this can be done using list tag in play framework but not sure how to use.
All kind of inputs are appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You mean you want to get the value of the `<option>` tag? Or rather, the value that is in the select box?

Comment: I want the list of words returned in suggestionlist variable to be the options for select tag.For example
suggestionlist : {'abc','def','ghi'}
Then
   <select id="birthyear" name="birthyear">
    <option >abc</option>
    <option >def</option>
    <option >ghi</option>
    <option >suggestionlist[4]</option>

    </select>

Comment: Ok Ill give it my best shot

Comment: OOH i understand, ill put it as an answer

Comment: Give me a few minutes to create a test version, i'd prefer to give you accurate information.

Comment: Does this help in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Play! Actions](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaActions).

Instead of using "render(suggestionlist)", either have this function return the list and call the function from within your action, or build this into your Play! Action. Then, within your Action, you can return "Ok(views.html.thePathToYourTemplate(explore()))", or "Ok(views.html.thePathToYourTemplate(suggestionList))", respectively.

Then, within your [Play! template](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTemplates), you can declare the list at the top, and loop through the contents of the list to build your select box.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the direction i am implementing it.will update if I face any issue :)

Comment: Could you please help me a little more.
I have a input text box, and on a keypress i want to call this java function "populate"( in controllers/application.java).This function returns a list of string and I want to use these value as my options for a selection tab.
I know this a kind of detailed help I am asking but I dont have much knowledge of Play actions and controlleres.So your help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure on how big you want the list to be, but give your option tags id's and then in the `<script>` area of your code, you can do:

```
_Array = [];
_Array[0] = "option1" // Array stores the Id's of your option tags....
_Array[1] = "option2"
_Array[2] = 'ect
_Array[3] = 'ect'
for(x=0;x<4;x++)
{
optionName = document.createTextNode(SuggestionListVAriable);
options = document.getElementById(_Array[x]);
options.appendChild(optionName);
}
```

Not quite sure if this answers your question...

Comment: Maybe you could put that In your current existing loop, That way you could use an index number for your suggestion list variable?

Comment: Actually I am using play framework.and so I am looking for a way to use list tag something like this
     <ul>
    #{list items:products, as:'product'}
        <li>${product}</li>
    #{/list}
    </ul>

Comment: Oh i apologize then, I don't have too much experience with play framework, i just gave a javascript answer.